# How to add a title in Doughnut chart chart.js React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I want to add a Title for the Doughnut chart in my React app but for some reason it doesn't work. I have this code:

```
const chartData = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: [
          Colors.primary,
          Colors.secondary,
          Colors.danger,
          Colors.warning
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
          'rgb(143, 0, 180, 0.3)',
          'rgb(0, 196, 204, 0.3)',
          'rgb(206, 0, 0, 0.3)',
          'rgb(255, 179, 0, 0.3)'
        ],
        hoverOffset: 10
      }]
    };

    const options = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: false,
        position: 'right',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        fontSize: 20,
        text: 'Tickets'
      }
    }
```

```
        <Doughnut 
          data = { chartData } 
          options = { options }
        />
```

What could have gone wrong here? I also want to place the labels on the right side of the chart, but it doesn't work as well. Below is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Chart.js version 3 `title`, `subtitle`, `legend` and `tooltip` are plugins and their options must be defined in plugins node.
As far as I have seen, react-chartjs-2 is working with Chartjs version >= 3.

```
const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
      position: 'right',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      fontSize: 20, // <--- this is not a managed option since CHART.JS 3
      text: 'Tickets'
    }
  }
}
```